# Quickitem in qml image is blured when image is sacled

Tags: qt, qml

I place a quickitem component in qml Image and draw some polygons with a pen of 0 line-width when I scale the image with the mouse wheel, the polygon looks blurred, how can the polygon look the same as they do(0 line-width graphicsitem should look very thin?) in QGraphicsView?

what can I do to make the 0 line-width polygon looks like the 0 line-width polygons in QGraphicsView?

Comment: Have you tried `sourceSize: Qt.size(width, height)` to resample your source image at a higher resolution?

Comment: I tried that, but the result is the same

Comment: Please supply a repro case. (1) source image, (2) QML code you've tried.